Getting google oauth tokens using "code" with python
I want to create an auth flow using react + python
Here is an example of how to do it with react + node.js:
const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.body.code);

But I want to rewrite it using Python and I'm struggling to find any information about how to use that "code" I get from react with Python

So you want to feed the google api python client library a code and have it return the auth to you?   and the code is coming from react?  try going though google_auth_oauthlib.flow

@LindaLawton-DaImTo. I have tried. I used  flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(...) and flow.fetch_token(code=code) but I'm getting "(invalid_grant) Bad Request"

Ok, now it is working. A few things to mention

The "code" that you will get in your front-end app is one-time only.
If you run your Python code more than once you will get "(invalid_grant) Bad Request"
you should set scopes=None. The scope should be defined in your FE app and that scope will be used.
Use redirect_uri='postmessage' to avoid (redirect_uri_mismatch)

Here is the final solution that worked for me:
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

def main():
  flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'credentials.json',
    scopes=None,
    redirect_uri='postmessage'
    )
  
  code = '4/0AdMrXxBRtzibvQgCGtovw7RkMGgvKjlaBaicjlOmbR6LIrYfHr7m799MZB_2GlsfIb-twe'
  return flow.fetch_token(code=code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  token = main()
  print(token)


postmessage  interesting.  what type of client did you create?  where did you read about that?
